# Quais são as exceções nativas do PHP?

Tags: php, exceção

Onde é possível verificar todas as *exceptions* (nativas) que podem ser lançadas pelo PHP? Procurei e só encontrei formas de tratamento com `try/catch`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As [**exceções nativas**](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php) são:

- [`BadFunctionCallException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badfunctioncallexception.php)

  > Ocorre quando um *callback* refere-se a uma *função* indefinida ou se alguns argumentos estão faltando.
- [`BadMethodCallException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php)

  > Ocorre quando um *callback* refere-se a um *método* não definido ou se alguns argumentos estão faltando.
- [`DomainException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando um valor não adere a um domínio de dados válido.
- [`InvalidArgumentException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.invalidargumentexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada se um argumento não é do tipo esperado.
- [`LengthException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.lengthexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada se um comprimento (*length*) é inválido.
- [`LogicException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.logicexception.php)

  > Exceção que representa erro na lógica do programa. Esse tipo de exceção deve levar diretamente a uma correção em seu código.
- [`OutOfBoundsException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.outofboundsexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando um valor não é uma chave válida. Isso representa erros que não podem ser detectados em tempo de compilação.
- [`OutOfRangeException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.outofrangeexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando um índice inválido foi solicitado. Isso representa erros que devem ser detectados em tempo de compilação.
- [`OverflowException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.overflowexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando adicionando um elemento a um *recipiente* cheio.
- [`RangeException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.rangeexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada para indicar erros de intervalo (*range*) durante a execução do programa. Normalmente isso significa que houve um erro aritmético, exceto *under/overflow*. Esta é a versão de tempo de execução de [DomainException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domainexception.php).
- [`RuntimeException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.runtimeexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada se ocorrer um erro que só pode ser encontrado em tempo de execução.
- [`UnderflowException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.underflowexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando realiza-se uma operação inválida em um *recipiente* vazio, como a remoção de um elemento.
- [`UnexpectedValueException`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.unexpectedvalueexception.php)

  > Exceção lançada quando um valor não corresponde com um conjunto de valores. Normalmente, isso acontece quando uma função chama outra função e espera que o valor de retorno seja de um determinado tipo.

Answer (score 13):

Em relação ao PHP 7, foi implementado as exceções nos erros comuns do PHP, como `Warning`, `Fatal Error` e `Parse Error`.

Aqui vai a lista dos erros que podem ser capturados em PHP 7:

## Error

É um erro qualquer, como um `Warning` ou um `Fatal Error`. É a classe base para todos os outros erros que serão demonstrados a seguir.

## ArithmeticError

é lançada quando ocorre um erro durante a execução de operações matemáticas. No PHP 7.0, estes erros incluem tentar executar uma BitShift por um valor negativo, e qualquer chamada para intDiv () que resultaria em um valor fora os possíveis limites de um número inteiro.

## DivisionByZeroError

Derivado de `ArithmeticError`, como o próprio nome diz, é lançada quando você tenta fazer uma operação de divisão por 0.

## ParseError

É lançada quando ocorre um erro durante a análise de código PHP, por exemplo, como em um `eval` que é chamado. Creio que outro caso é quando você inclui um outro script PHP e nele há erros.

## TypeError

Esse erro é lançado quando você tem passagem de argumentos para funções cujo tipo é o insperado, quando o retorno é diferente do que é definido na função. No manual também fala que no modo estrito há o lançamento do mesmo quando você um número inválido de argumentos para uma função.

## AssertionError

É lançada quando uma afirmação feita por meio de assert() retorna falso.

## Esses erros são exceções?

Parece-me que o PHP resolveu tratar os erros diferentemente das exceções.
Todos esses erros descritos anteriormente **não herdam** a classe `Exception` tradicional do PHP. Para capturá-los, é necessário adicionar a interface `Throwable` na opção `catch`.

Assim:

```
try{
    $result = 59 / 0;
} catch (Throwable $e) {
   var_dump($e instanceof DivisionByZeroError); // bool(true)
}
```

No PHP 7, tanto exceções como os erros implementam a interface `Throwable`.

Comment: Bom complemento WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 6):

Das exceções nativas, é bom saber que algumas estendem outras, formando a [seguinte hierarquia](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php):

- LogicException (extends Exception)

  - BadFunctionCallException

    - BadMethodCallException
  - DomainException
  - InvalidArgumentException
  - LengthException
  - OutOfRangeException
- RuntimeException (extends Exception)

  - OutOfBoundsException
  - OverflowException
  - RangeException
  - UnderflowException
  - UnexpectedValueException

É interessante criar exceções mais específicas no domínio de sua aplicação, estendendo as exceções já existentes.

```
<?php 

class QueroBatataException extends UnexpectedValueException { }

class QueroCebolaException extends UnexpectedValueException { }

function batata($nomeLegume) {
    if ($nomeLegume !== 'batata') {
        throw new QueroBatataException('Me dê batata');
    }

    echo 'Huuun Batata!' . PHP_EOL;
}


function cebola($nomeLegume) {
    if ($nomeLegume !== 'cebola') {
        throw new QueroCebolaException('Me dê cebola');
    }

    echo 'Huuun Cebola!' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Assim no seu código, é possível você fazer isso:

```
<?php

$legume = 'batata';

try { 
    batata($legume);
    cebola($legume);
} catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// Saída:
// Huuun Batata! 
// Me dê cebola
```

Veja o [código em execução](https://3v4l.org/K2ek7).